# Paypal Integration using php not deducting money from buyers fake account in sandbox

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I created a seller account and buyer account in payapal sandbox.Then tried to integrate paypal using php.I used DoDirectPayment Api of paypal to do the transaction using php.I did the transaction using buyer dummy credit card number and the transaction was successful.The seller got his money, ie the money is credited to his account but the money is not deducting from buyers account.Why this is happening?
Thank you
Regard,
AlenLee MJ

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using buyer credit card, use buyer paypal account details and try. It should work.

Comment: ya i am using buyer paypal account details.

Comment: I am also getting the same issue in my recent Rails application. Did you get any solution regarding this issue?

Answer (score 0):

DoDirectPayment API does not allow you to deduct the payment from paypal account it only accept credit card so the payment will only deduct from the credit card not from paypal account to deduct the payment from paypal account you should use ExpressCheckout API of Paypal it allows to deduct payment from paypal account.